# Titan backend exception on connection

Tags: cassandra, graph-databases, titan

I am using Titan 0.54 and Cassandra 2.1.6.

I have written a Java program that is able to connect to Titan and run a workload on my local Cassandra cluster. When I try to run the same software on a another machine (with its own cluster) I get the error below (with storage.backend set to "cassandrathrift"):

```
Exception in thread "main" com.thinkaurelius.titan.core.TitanException: Could not execute operation due to backend exception
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.util.BackendOperation.execute(BackendOperation.java:44)
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.util.BackendOperation.execute(BackendOperation.java:144)
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.configuration.backend.KCVSConfiguration.get(KCVSConfiguration.java:92)
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.configuration.BasicConfiguration.isFrozen(BasicConfiguration.java:93)
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.graphdb.configuration.GraphDatabaseConfiguration.<init>(GraphDatabaseConfiguration.java:1289)
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.core.TitanFactory.open(TitanFactory.java:93)
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.core.TitanFactory$Builder.open(TitanFactory.java:134)
    at com.x.tweetgraph.writer.graph.TitanConnector.getConnection(TitanConnector.java:17)
    at com.x.tweetgraph.writer.graph.GraphManager.loadGraph(GraphManager.java:186)
    at com.x.tweetgraph.writer.graph.GraphManager.init(GraphManager.java:99)
    at com.x.tweetgraph.writer.graph.Main.main(Main.java:26)
Caused by: com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.PermanentBackendException: Permanent failure in storage backend
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.cassandra.thrift.CassandraThriftKeyColumnValueStore.convertException(CassandraThriftKeyColumnValueStore.java:249)
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.cassandra.thrift.CassandraThriftKeyColumnValueStore.getNamesSlice(CassandraThriftKeyColumnValueStore.java:148)
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.cassandra.thrift.CassandraThriftKeyColumnValueStore.getNamesSlice(CassandraThriftKeyColumnValueStore.java:91)
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.cassandra.thrift.CassandraThriftKeyColumnValueStore.getSlice(CassandraThriftKeyColumnValueStore.java:80)
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.configuration.backend.KCVSConfiguration$1.call(KCVSConfiguration.java:95)
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.configuration.backend.KCVSConfiguration$1.call(KCVSConfiguration.java:92)
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.util.BackendOperation.execute(BackendOperation.java:133)
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.util.BackendOperation$1.call(BackendOperation.java:147)
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.util.BackendOperation.executeDirect(BackendOperation.java:56)
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.util.BackendOperation.execute(BackendOperation.java:42)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: TimedOutException()
    at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.Cassandra$multiget_slice_result$multiget_slice_resultStandardScheme.read(Cassandra.java:14696)
    at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.Cassandra$multiget_slice_result$multiget_slice_resultStandardScheme.read(Cassandra.java:14633)
    at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.Cassandra$multiget_slice_result.read(Cassandra.java:14559)
    at org.apache.thrift.TServiceClient.receiveBase(TServiceClient.java:78)
    at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.Cassandra$Client.recv_multiget_slice(Cassandra.java:741)
    at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.Cassandra$Client.multiget_slice(Cassandra.java:725)
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.cassandra.thrift.CassandraThriftKeyColumnValueStore.getNamesSlice(CassandraThriftKeyColumnValueStore.java:129)
    ... 18 more
```

With storage.backend set to "cassandra" I get the following:

```
Caused by: TimedOutException()
    at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.Cassandra$multiget_slice_result$multiget_slice_resultStandardScheme.read(Cassandra.java:14696)
    at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.Cassandra$multiget_slice_result$multiget_slice_resultStandardScheme.read(Cassandra.java:14633)
    at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.Cassandra$multiget_slice_result.read(Cassandra.java:14559)
    at org.apache.thrift.TServiceClient.receiveBase(TServiceClient.java:78)
    at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.Cassandra$Client.recv_multiget_slice(Cassandra.java:741)
    at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.Cassandra$Client.multiget_slice(Cassandra.java:725)
    at com.netflix.astyanax.thrift.ThriftColumnFamilyQueryImpl$4$1.internalExecute(ThriftColumnFamilyQueryImpl.java:533)
    at com.netflix.astyanax.thrift.ThriftColumnFamilyQueryImpl$4$1.internalExecute(ThriftColumnFamilyQueryImpl.java:530)
    at com.netflix.astyanax.thrift.AbstractOperationImpl.execute(AbstractOperationImpl.java:60)
    ... 24 more
```

Both options work on my local setup (single-node Cassandra cluster). From cassandra.yaml:

```
listen_address: 136.225.5.31
start_native_transport: true
native_transport_port: 12742
start_rpc: true
rpc_address: 136.225.5.31
rpc_port: 12760
```

The setup I am trying to connect to is a three-node cluster:

```
listen_interface: eth1
start_native_transport: true
native_transport_port: 12742
start_rpc: true
rpc_interface: eth1
rpc_port: 12760
```

On the first setup I get a Titan connection using the rpc_address + rpc_port, but when I try that on the second setup I get the errors above.

Do I need to use a different setting than the node IP for storage.hostname to account for rpc_interface being specified instead of rpc_address in the second setup? Or what could the problem be?

I can connect to the second cluster using cqlsh (and with other software I have written), so it's not an issue with the cluster.

Comment: firewall rules? can you telnet to the ports?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve the problem.

I had neglected to set the `storage.cassandra.replication-factor` property in TitanFactory.build() so Titan was using the default replication factor of 1, which worked on my single node test cluster. Apparently there was some issue with one of the three nodes, so I ran nodetool repair on each node and set `storage.cassandra.replication-factor` to 3. That fixed the issue.